# Does $L_1$ Convergence imply almost everywhere convergence for the Set of all increasing functions on $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

We know that $L_1$ convergence does not imply convergence a.e. in general. However, consider the following set
$$S=\{f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]\mid f(x)\geq f(y) \quad \forall x\geq y\}.$$ Take any  sequence $\{f_n\}_1^\infty\subset S$  that is converging to $f$  with respect to $L_1$ norm.  Is it possible that convergence in $L_1$ implies pointwise a.e.  convergence in this case? I just couldn't  find an example to show this is not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

**Lemma.** Suppose $f\in S$, $x\in(0,1)$, $f$ is continuous at $x$ and $\epsilon>0$. There exists $\delta>0$ such that if $g\in S$ and $|g(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon$ then $||f-g||_1\ge\epsilon\delta/2$.

Proof: Suppose first $g(x)-f(x)>\epsilon$. Choose $\delta>0$ so that if $I=(x,x+\delta)$ then $I\subset(0,1)$ and $$|f(t)-f(x)|<\epsilon/2\quad(t\in I).$$If $t\in I$ then $$g(t)-f(t)\ge g(x)-(f(x)+\epsilon/2)>\epsilon/2,$$so $$||g-f||_1\ge\epsilon\delta/2.$$

If on the other hand $g(x)-f(x)<-\epsilon$ a similar argument works with $I=(x-\delta,x)$.

**Corollary.** If $f,f_n\in S$ and $||f_n-f||_1\to0$ then $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere on $[0,1]$.

Because a monotone function is continuous almost everywhere.

**Exercise.** Explain the relevance of the example $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
-1+nx,&(0\le x\le 1/n),
\\0,&(1/n\le x\le 1).\end{cases}$$

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $f$ is continuous. I don't see where that is stated in the question.

Comment: @user159517 I thought it was... fixed.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks a lot! I don't see any harm to extend the corollary to $[0,1]$. Am I right?

Comment: @user1122 Oh of course; the $(0,1)$ in the current version is just silly. The notation was left over from the previous version, that stated (incorrectly) convergence at every point of $(0,1)$.